# Comparing Forecast Errors

Tags: forecasting, error, diebold-mariano-test

I want to compare my VAR-forecast to an ARMA-benchmark. The VAR forecast has a smaller MPSE (mean squared prediction error) and I want to check for significance. For this purpose I applied the Diebold-Mariano test with Stata but it gives always complete insignificance. Many Stata-users weren't sure about the automatically selected maxlag-option, me neither.

Is there any other test to compare MPSEs of unnested models?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

While you are asking for another test, the Diebold-Mariano test is really just what you need. You could even implement it yourself - it is so simple.

- Regress the difference between the forecast losses (the loss series from forecast 1 minus the loss series from forecast 2) on a constant (i.e. an intercept).
- Test whether the constant is equal to zero in population. In other words, test the significance of the intercept.
- Use autocorrelation-robust standard errors in the test **if** you have a forecast horizon $h$ greater than 1; set the lag of the autocorrelation equal to $h-1$ when calculating the autocorrelation-robust standard error. For $h=1$, use vanilla standard errors.

If you reject the null of the constant being equal to zero, you conclude there is evidence against equal predictive ability of forecast 1 and forecast 2. If you cannot reject, then there is not enough evidence against that.